# ASP.NET Core 6 : Session Timeout is not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to adjust my ASP.NET Core 6 project to **use a Session Timeout of 50 Minutes.** **Default timeout is 20 Minutes** as per the Microsoft Documentation.

Below I have attached my **Program.cs, Startup.cs and web.config** files codings. While testing in localhost, when the session time is expired after 50 Minutes, it will redirect to Error page of my application. But after Publishing and **Releasing in Server, the Session is Expired in Default Timeout of 20 Minutes.**

**My Program.cs file Contains :**

```
using OtherSportsMaster;

namespace OtherSportsMaster
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
                })

                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).UseIISIntegration().UseStartup<Startup>()
               .UseUrls("http://localhost:5001")
                .Build();

            host.Run();
            //CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

**My Startup.cs file Contains :**

```
using OtherSportsMaster.Data;
using OtherSportsMaster.Models;
using OtherSportsMaster.Models.MasterDAL;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS;
using System.Data.Common;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace OtherSportsMaster
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            //BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(IISServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);    
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            //Set Session Timeout. Default is 20 minutes.
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                //options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNetCore.Session";
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            //.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            //services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped<CommanCls>();
            services.AddScoped<DBConnectionCls>();
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
            });
            //services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
            //{
            //    x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            //    x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            //    x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;

            //    x.ValueCountLimit = 10;
            //    x.MemoryBufferThreshold = Int32.MaxValue;
            //});
            //services.AddMvc();
            //services.AddMvc(options =>
            //{
            //    options.Filters.Add(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute));
            //    options.MaxModelBindingCollectionSize = int.MaxValue;
            //});
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                //app.UseHsts();
            }
            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc();
            AppHttpContext.Services = app.ApplicationServices;

            //app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            //{
            //    context.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = null; // unlimited I guess
            //    await next.Invoke();
            //});

            //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            //{
            //    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            //        name: "default",      
            //        pattern: "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            //});
            //app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoute);
            // app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Master}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
            });

            //app.Run(async (context) =>
            //{
            //    await context.Response.WriteAsync("\"No ");
            //});
        }

    }
}
```

**My web.config file Contains :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.web>
            <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
        </system.web>
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <requestFiltering>
                    <requestLimits maxUrl="65536" maxQueryString="2097151" maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
                    <!-- 1 GB-->                                                    <!-- ~ 4GB -->
                </requestFiltering>
            </security>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:50:00" processPath=".\OtherSportsMaster.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
        <system.web.extensions>
            <scripting>
                <webServices>
                    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="86753090"/>
                </webServices>
            </scripting>
        </system.web.extensions>
    </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: ac80560e-7b73-4211-994b-881b5818045d-->
```

**In my Code, how can I achieve Session Timeout to 50 Minutes by changing Default Timeout 20 Minutes and after Session expired, on reloading have to navigate to Login Page instead of Error Page.**

Comment: The account on the Published machine doesn't have the permission to change the Session Timeout.

Comment: @jdweng - Can you please tell me which kind of account did I have to use.

Comment: It has to be an account that can change the Session Timeout.  It is a policy issue.  See : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-for-it-pro/idle-time-out-gpo-for-remote-desktop-services-sessions-not/m-p/3413579

Comment: I think you need to set the app pool's Idle Time-out option in IIS.  (it's default is 20 minutes, so if no actions are taken within 20 minutes it will shutdown and then restart on the next request received)

Comment: @pcalkins - Yes, I got now have changed the Application pool's Idle Time-out in ISS from 20 Minutes to 1 Hour. The Session is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As @pcalkins said, you need check below things:

1.Check your application pool advanced settings to make sure the idle-timeout value is exceed the 20 min. This settings will stop the application pool after 20 min if there is no request send to the request.

[image]

2.Check your IIS server contain the proxy or ARR, if you have it, you need to check the if the server has the specific setting enabled like Affinity cookie. Which means the request should go to the right server according to that cookie.

3.If above all not working, you need check if there contains the specific module which clear the cookie. To troubleshooting this issue, you should use fail request tracing to see what happened inside the logs.

Comment: Can you tell how and where can I found and change the Application pool Idle Time-out settings, can I able to find it through my System. **(Example : Settings -> Application Pool -> Idle Timeout).**

Comment: No , its inside the iis settings. You could find it after open the IIS manager=> application pool =>that web apps application pool => advanced settings.

Comment: Any update? Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the Update, the information was very much useful for me, finally have solved the issue.